# How to remove unnecessary solutions in 'solve' function

Tags: python, sympy

I'm a newbie learning python. I have a question! This is my code:

```
from sympy import *
f = x**3 - y**3 - 2*x*y + 6
fx = diff(f, x)
fy = diff(f, y)

sol = solve([fx,fy], [x,y])
```

Result:

```
(-2/3, 2/3)
(0, 0)
(-3*(-1/3 - sqrt(3)*I/3)**2/2, -1/3 - sqrt(3)*I/3)
(-3*(-1/3 + sqrt(3)*I/3)**2/2, -1/3 + sqrt(3)*I/3)
```

I don't understand what is the 3rd and 4th result meaning? Is there any way to remove it? Anyone have any help or can give some pointers?

Comment: What do you mean "their meaning" ? They are math value too, and they solve the equatio too

Comment: The unwanted results takes into account imaginary number. If You're using `SymPy`, You have to declare Your symbols as real values, e.g. `x = Symbol('x', real=True)`

Answer (score 2):

The unwanted results takes into account imaginary numbers. You have to declare Your symbols as real values:

```
x = Symbol('x', real=True)
y = Symbol('y', real=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols('x y', real=True)
f = x**3 - y**3 - 2*x*y + 6
fx = diff(f, x)
fy = diff(f, y)
sol = solve([fx,fy], [x,y])
```